# Compartilhando rotas no express

Tags: node.js, express.js, router

Estou tentando fazer um controller genérico que irá disponibilizar as rotas básicas de crud, a ideia é estender esse controller e poder adicionar algumas rotas customizadas que são inerentes apenas aquela classe.

Segue exemplo:

```js
export default class BaseController {

constructor(model, key) {
    this.model = model;
    this.modelName = model.modelName.toLowerCase();
    this.key = key;
}

route() {
    const router = new Router();

    router.get("/", (req, res) => {
      this
        .list()
        .then(ok(res))
        .then(null, fail(res));
    });

    router.post("/", (req, res) => {
      this
        .create(req.body)
        .then(ok(res))
        .then(null, fail(res));
    });

    router.get("/:key", (req, res) => {
      this
        .read(req.params.key)
        .then(ok(res))
        .then(null, fail(res));
    });

    router.put("/:key", (req, res) => {
      this
        .update(req.params.key, req.body)
        .then(ok(res))
        .then(null, fail(res)); user
    });

    router.delete("/:key", (req, res) => {
      this
        .delete(req.params.key)
        .then(ok(res))
        .then(null, fail(res));
    });

    return router;
  }
}
```

E na minha classe filha seria:

```js
export default class UserController extends BaseController {
    constructor() {
        super(User, '_id');
    }

    route() {
        let router = super.route();

        router.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
            res.send('foo ');
        });

        return router;
    }
}
```

Mas a rota simplesmente não existe quando eu tento acessar "http://localhost:8080/api/user/foo", segue codigo que registra as rotas:

```js
import { version } from '../../package.json';
import { Router } from 'express';
import facets from './facets';
import { UserController } from '../controllers';

export default ({ config, db }) => {
 let api = Router();

 // mount the facets resource
 api.use('/facets', facets({ config, db }));

 api.use('/user', new UserController().route());

 // perhaps expose some API metadata at the root
 api.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ version });
 });

 return api;
}
```

O objeto de rotas está retornando da classe super preenchido mas nada funciona, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Não responde sua pergunta, mas o que você está tentando fazer já está pronto no Sails.js e outros frameworks.